# Can't change animation duration for deselect anim

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I try to implement custom animation for cells in UICollectionView cell, but I can't implement animation for deselecting action.

I use swift and developing project for iOS >= 10

It is example project
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nUVVBFBA7N6ZHNIKOdHf21j4rv1w0SfL/view?usp=sharing

It is code from example project

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var selectedIndex: Int?

        if let selectedIndexPathes = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
            if (selectedIndexPathes.count > 0) {
                selectedIndex = selectedIndexPathes[0].item
            }
        }

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        if (selectedIndex == indexPath.item) {
            cell.configureForSelected()
        }
        else {
            cell.configureForUnselected()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var selectedIndex: Int?

        if let selectedIndexPathes = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
            if (selectedIndexPathes.count > 0) {
                selectedIndex = selectedIndexPathes[0].item
            }
        }

        if (selectedIndex == indexPath.item) {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 200)
        }

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
            collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

                if (self.lastSelectedIndexPath != nil) {
                    let lastCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: self.lastSelectedIndexPath!) as! CollectionViewCell
                    lastCell.configureForUnselected()
                }

                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
                cell.configureForSelected()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
```

[image]

How I can smoothly animate deselecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to implement the below method in your code,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

            if (self.lastSelectedIndexPath != nil) {
                let lastCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: self.lastSelectedIndexPath!) as! CollectionViewCell
                lastCell.configureForUnselected()
            }

      }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is work. omartarek32 answer fix my problem too. Which solution better?

Comment: Yes, that is better as well but if you will take child view inside the table view then above @omartarek32 solution will not work you need to use my solution for performing the action on child view of table view cell.

Comment: By calling your function, you are just animating container view that is inside the table view cell but not table view cell itself. so, table view height had remained the same. So, if you want to reflect the height then you need to deselect cell manually like I did or you can directly animate the table view cell as mentioned above in @omartarek32 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very easy from you code 
the problem in the collection view cell

please replace the functions inside this class with those

```
 public func setup() {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}

public func configureForSelected() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}

public func configureForUnselected() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}
```

instated of

```
  public func setup() {

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}

public func configureForSelected() {
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}

public func configureForUnselected() {
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is work. Can you explain please. Why animation depend from this changes?

Comment: that is because the contentView itself does not animated, the cell it self is animated fine, but its content view not animated fine.
please try to add the following line inside "awakeFromNib() " function for your "CollectionViewCell", and check the behavior:

self.contentView.backgroundColor = .green